# How do I compile a Nim application that runs without a console window?

Tags: console, nim-lang

Is there a way to compile a Nim application that doesn't open a console when it's executed? Unless I'm missing something, the official documentation doesn't show any compiler options that would do this. I really want a program to perform tasks in the background without always having a console window showing.

Answer (score 6):

`nim --app:gui c file` should do the trick according to http://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html

Comment: When I do this, I get strange errors.


`C:/Nim/dist/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgdi32`

`C:/Nim/dist/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcomdlg32`

Comment: That discussion is a little bit unclear to me. I don't know very much about MinGW or how to mess around with compilers, and I don't have any C background, so the language they are using goes over my head.

Comment: For me this worked without problems after cross compiling from Linux ( `nim c -d:mingw --app:gui file.nim`)